# Permission denied when I tried to create a folder in root

Tags: root, mkdir, permission-denied

Hi I tried to create a folder for ssh key in root with this command:

```
mkdir /root/.ssh && chown -R root:root /root && chmod -R 770 /root
```

and I have permission denied:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/root/.ssh’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you running as root when you try to execute the command? Are you using anything like SELinux?

Comment: Yes, I'm in root folder when I try to run the command and I use ubuntu 14.04 @Patrick

Comment: No, not in root folder, are you the root user (or using `sudo`)?

Comment: Can you please share the permissions currently on /root?

Comment: @Lau If you're using `sudo`, please show that in your command. We need to see exactly what you're doing.

Answer (score 3):

The super user has no real reason to have SSH access.  It's is safer to set up an ordinary user with SSH access to the machine and then use `sudo` when needed. You can even set `PermitRootLogin no` in your `sshd_config` file (under `/etc` somewhere) unless you, for some reason, think you may need to actually log in as root to unbreak the system at some point (which you can do from the console anyway, if you have physical access to the machine).

Having said that, you are probably executing your commands as an ordinary user which is why you don't have permission to perform the operations.

Never change ownership or permissions on the `/root` directory though. They are correctly set up from the start and shouldn't need changing (which may open up for security holes later).

On all the systems I've set up, the original contents of `/root` and the directory itself is totally untouched.  Nothing added, nothing taken away, nothing modified.  The `root` account is *special*, and you should rarely, if ever, see an interactive root prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the user to root "*#su root*" OR you can use the below command with sudo prefix *sudo mkdir /root/.ssh && chown -R root:root /root && chmod -R 770 /root*

Note: your local must be added in sudoers file.

Comment: Note that all parts of your second command needs `sudo` and that you shouldn't fiddle with the ownership or permissions of the `/root` directory itself, ever.